# Django 1.8 HstoreField admin interface

Tags: python, django, postgresql, hstore, django-1.8

New Django 1.8 provides HstoreField. 
I have extended user model with HstoreField data

```
**#models.py**
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import HStoreField
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Profile(AbstractUser):

    data = HStoreField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

**#admin.py**
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass
```

Now, how can i add HstoreField to my admin interface?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `django.contrib.postgres` has been added to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'yourapp',
)
```

Also note that per the Django Docs, [Psycopg2 2.5 or higher is required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/).

Once you have confirmed the above, you should be able to enter the following in your `data` field:

`{"a": "1", "b": "2"}`

I had some trouble with PostGres 9.1 not having HStore immediately available, so you may need to run the following on your database:

`CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`